# Would Nexus 4 bought from UK work in India?

Tags: nexus-4

I bought a Google Nexus 4 LG make from UK, will it work in India?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is only one model of the Nexus 4. It should work with no problems.

On the off chance that there are problems, there were also different radio images released for different areas. Almost all of them (if not all) can be [found over here, on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2087227). The version for India is 0.54.

If needed, these images can be flashed using [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) or possibly using a [custom-recovery](/questions/tagged/custom-recovery).

As long as your carrier in India uses a frequency that the Nexus 4 supports, the hardware itself isn't locked to any geographical location.

From [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_4_e960-5048.php):

**2G Networks**:

- GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900

**3G Networks**:

- HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100
- HSDPA 900 / 2100

Comment: However as per my discussion with the Phone retailer , they are saying that Phone is EU compatible and hence it would not be working with Indian service provides.
Currently I am in UK but I have to use it in India after my travel back to India.
I am confused that in case it didn't work in India my investment on Nexus 4 phone would be waste.
Please guide what should I do ?

Comment: The phone retailer people were wrong. The Nexus 4 should work in India, no matter where you purchased it, as long as your carrier supports the frequencies it supports. (Check with your carrier in India). I've updated the answer with the Nexus 4 frequencies.

Comment: Thank you so much again , will check for the Service providers in India and the frequency range they operate on.

Comment: Is there any way, it could be traced/identified by the Product Serial No OR IMEI No that this phone is EU specific or can be used internationally?
Retailer was saying that it is unlocked and can be used with any network in EU however they were not sure about that It can be used or not in INDIA.

Have you come across with any similar case where any Nexus Phone is location specific.

I am not being convinced that If the phone is unlocked why it can't be used across the globe , is there any other thing which plays role in making it EU specific?

Comment: The hardware and IMEI for the Nexus 4 are international, not EU specific. It *should* work perfectly. If it's a little weird in India, just flash the radio from the link above (Does not require factory reset). If you feel satisfied with the answer, feel free to upvote it and/or mark it as "Accepted".